# ACCESS: Summing all of the donations for each member

Tags: ms-access

I have simple database that stores out members and the animals they have adopted:

```
Member(Mem_ID, Forename, Surname, Street ... Email)
Adopted(Adopt_ID, Animal_ID, Mem_ID, Date, Amount)
Animal(Animal_ID, Name, Habitat, etc)
```

I'm trying to create a query that will return the total amount of donations each month made by each member.

So for example Mr Smith gives £300 to Pogo and £200 to Bobo it should return a single row with his Surname, Address and total donation (£500). It will then do this for all other members.

I can do this in PHP/SQL but cannot see how to do this easily in ACCESS.

I appreciate any support on this one!

Comment: MS Access supports SQL as well if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-queries-a9739a09-d3ff-4f36-8ac3-5760249fb65c

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT      MONTHNAME(MONTH(dDate)) AS [Month]
            , Forename & ' ' & Surname AS Member
            , sName AS [Animal Name]
            , SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM        (Member LEFT JOIN Adopted ON Member.Mem_ID = Adopted.Mem_ID)
                    LEFT JOIN Animal ON Adopted.Animal_ID = Animal.Animal_ID
GROUP BY    MONTHNAME(MONTH(dDate))
            , Forename & ' ' & Surname
            , sName
            , MONTH(dDate)
ORDER BY    MONTH(dDate)
```

I've renamed the `Name` and `Date` fields as they're reserved by Access and could cause problems.